# Using the same function to style each repeated element slightly differently in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to know how to properly reuse controllers, modules and functions in AngularJS to make a slightly different offset for each of the posts (placeholders for now just showing where the posts will be) in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9XeEqMxdUGDXtrS5TmR0?p=preview).

When later ngRepeat will output, for example, 6 posts, I want each of them to use the same code as in the mousePosition() function, but for each element calculate the x and y coordinates with a new variable to increase the gap accordingly.

I thought the radian offset between posts will work but it is very narrow, so you may ignore that. The question is about how to have this code applied on each repeated element with a different variable, like a counter.

```
angular.module('mouseMovement', [])
  .controller('MouseMovementController', ['$scope', function MouseMovementController($scope) {

    numberOfPosts = 1
    radiansBetweenPosts = (90 / numberOfPosts) * Math.PI / 180

    $scope.mousePosition = function(event) {

      mouseXpercent = event.pageX / window.innerWidth * 2

      x = Math.cos(mouseXpercent * Math.PI + radiansBetweenPosts) * 50 + 50
      y = Math.sin(mouseXpercent * Math.PI + radiansBetweenPosts) * -50 + 50

      $scope.position = {
        left: x + '%',
        top: y + '%'
      }

    }
  }])
```

EDIT: I just had an idea that perhaps the better idea is to loop through the child elements within the div that contains all the posts?

Comment: you want a directive with isolated scope if you want this done on each one

Answer (score 0):

You are right, a loop is the best way to do it.

Angular doesn't need to be involved in this basic process either.

I wrote up a little generator you are free to use or reference if you like:

```js
// generate element function
function el(n, type) {
  let children = []
  while (n) {
    children.push(document.createElement(type || 'div'))
    n--
  }
  return children
}

function genNodes() {
    // for loop generates each child node

    for (let child of children) {
      let nInContainer = container.childElementCount

      // do whatever you need to do to each element
      // i.e. apply id, class, or style

      child.id = `child_${nInContainer}`
      child.style.background = `rgba(100,${100*nInContainer%255},100,1)`
      child.style.color = `rgba(${88*nInContainer%255},255,255,1)`
      child.style.fontSize = `2px`
      child.style.textAlign = `center`
      child.innerHTML = `hello I am child ${nInContainer}`

      //child.style.paddingLeft = `${(nInContainer/children.length)*window.innerWidth}px`
      child.onmouseenter = () => {
        child.style.fontSize = `${50+nInContainer}px`
        console.log(child.id)
      }

      child.onmouseleave = () => {
        child.style.height = ``
        child.style.fontSize = `2px`
      }
      container.appendChild(child)
    }
  }
  //
  //
  //

let container = el(1, 'div')[0]
let children = el(101, 'div')
container.style.overflow = `hidden`
  //////////
genNodes()
  //////////
document.body.appendChild(container)

//grab any element you want after adding to dom
container.children.child_100.style.fontSize = `150px`
```

you can play with the live code here:
http://codepen.io/blrzzzt/pen/ozGXKK